# PostgreSQL top 5 populous counties in each state

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rank

I have a problem for my databases class that I can't figure out.

I have a table called **counties** which is like this:

```
state_code | name | population
           |      |
           |      |
```

(there are multiple counties within each state_code)

There is another table called **states** which is just

```
state_code | name 
           |
           |
```

Anyway I need a query that returns the scheme (state_name, county_name, county_population), that lists in order of state name, the five most populous county names in each state in descending order of population, together with the population of those counties.

I have a query that produces the right scheme, but it shows too many results, not just the top 5:

```
SELECT state.name AS state_name, county.name AS county_name, county.population 
FROM state JOIN county ON state.code = county.state_code 
GROUP BY state.name, county.name, county.population
ORDER BY state.name, county.population DESC
```

I have attempted more complex solutions involving ranking, however our school only has PostgreSQL version 8.3 which does not have PARTITION OVER or RANK() which makes things very difficult.

Thanks

Comment: 8.3 is pretty ancient. You need to start planning for an upgrade. 8.3 is going end-of-life in Feb 2013, at which point no future bug fixes, security fixes or compatibility fixes will be released. See http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . Upgrading from 8.3 to 9.2 isn't a big jump in compatibility terms; you need to handle `standard_conforming_strings` and the `bytea_output` default change, but not much else. See the release notes. PostgreSQL is free, so there's really no excuse not to upgrade.

Comment: The OP might not have the administrative power to do the upgrade...

Comment: you are right didierc, unfortunately the computers in class run an outdated postgreSQL and I can't do anything about it. I have a solution which uses window functions but those solutions aren't accepted

Answer (score 2):

```
select state_name, county_name, population
from (
    select
        s.name state_name,
        c.name county_name,
        c.population,
        row_number() over(partition by s.state_code order by population desc) rn
    from
        states s
        inner join
        counties c on s.state_code = c.state_code
) s
where rn <= 5
order by state_name, population desc
```

The row_number window function numbers the rows inside each state. In the outer query I limit the row number to 5 or less.

Comment: You might want to use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` in order to deal with ties.

Comment: the OP said he didn't have access to the OVER PARTITION construct because its postgresql server is version 8.3

Answer (score 0):

This Solution is incredibly slow and painful, but I believe it should give you what you want. I am curious to see if anyone can come up with a more elegant solution.

```
 SELECT state.name AS state_name, county.name AS county_name, county.population
 FROM state JOIN county ON state.code = county.state_code
 WHERE  county.name IN (SELECT county.name, COUNT(*) FROM county
          INNER JOIN county AS second_county ON (county.name = second_county.name) AND 
          (county.state_code = second_county.state_code) AND (county.population < state.population) GROUP BY county.name HAVING COUNT(*) <=5)
GROUP BY state.name, county.name, county.population
ORDER BY state.name, county.population DESC
```